# Handle process termination scenrios on low memory

Tags: android, performance, memory-management, service

I am searching for best practices for App **restarting** scenarios on *low-end* phones, in which during app switching it restarts App with white screen and goes back to last screen where the user was previously. My question is how to save all the essential data in order to overcome such scenarios.

Comment: Save the data when the data changes. Use memory only as a cache.

Comment: @CommonsWare where to store this data

Comment: Use a SQLite database. Or, use `SharedPreferences`. Or, use some other form of file, typically on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Or, store it on a server somewhere.

Comment: @CommonsWare if we used SharedPreferences and store all required data in form of json then can it cause any overhead?

Comment: If you are going to use JSON, I would just use regular files. `SharedPreferences` adds no value here. There is always overhead when doing disk reads and writes, which is why you do them in background threads. Your in-memory cache should minimize the number of disk reads that you need to perform.

Comment: @CommonsWare can u please give any tutorial link on in-memory caches.for begginers like me i have never used it.

Comment: @ CommonWare don't saving in Application class came to rescue

Answer (score 0):

in that case application having onLowMemory() method in Application class
for example :

```
class MyApplication extends Application {

@Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
//  you can save your important data here as it is trigger when your application going to kill as it don't have enough memory
    }

}
```

please let me know if these not working for you.

Comment: it is called just after google map is just loaded if there is 3 tabs and in one of screen there is google map

Comment: That means you are having very low memory to work, try to free some memory.

Comment: but just app is opened

Comment: If you are not able to do these you can change installLocation to externalOnly which install application in external storage if there you are having memory

Comment: @ jitesh mohite i am not talking about storage space problem, i am asking about memory which is allocated to our app when it opens based on process priority

Comment: I have given you the alternate approach, but the problem is with your storage space if you gonna remove some space i am pretty much sure your application never kills.

Comment: @ jitesh mohite never kills means?

Comment: application is getting killed due to low memory and restart again when you start again.

Comment: @ jitesh mohite exactly that is the situation.can't we store it in application class

Comment: ya you can store it in application class when onLowMemory occure. try some example which store data in sharepreference and get whenEver you needed after lunching it again.